# Difference between Authorize and Request.IsAuthenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC and I am encountering the following piece of code very often:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
  // ...
}
```

Is the if-statement really necessary? Can somebody please explain the differences between the two?

Comment: The "Login" process has 2 faces: Authentication (where the user provides a credential and it gets validated) and the Authorization (where a valid user checks if it can access some resource). Since those faces are executed in that order, the "if (Request.IsAuthenticated)" is, at least, redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `if` check should not be needed. The `[Authorize]` attribute does that, in fact it does more by checking role membership as well. Check out the implementation of `AuthorizeAttribute` [on GitHub](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) to see how it works under the covers.

Answer (score 3):

`Authorize` can check role membership. The `if` is redundant in this case as well.

That isn't a common pattern for ASP.NET MVC, you should ask who wrote the code.

This will just make testing a bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

The `[Authorize]` attribute means that a user has to be logged in to call the controller endpoint.

`Request.IsAuthenticated` is useful for condtionally running code for authenticated users e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

  somecodethatrunsforeverybody(); 
  if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    codethatrunsforauthenticatedusers();
  }

}
```

So there is no point in decorating an action with `[Authorize]` then wrapping the entire contents if an `if (Request.IsAuthenticated)`.  However it does have a use as per my example.

Comment: So there is no difference?

Comment: They are different and are for different purposes but decorating an action with `[Authorize]` then wrapping the entire contents if an `if (Request.IsAuthenticated)` is redundant.  The code in action/method will never be run unless the user is authenticated, due to the attribute.